# Adding values to a map state object one at a time

Tags: reactjs

I have a map as a state object as below

```
this.state = {
      imgSrcs: new Map([])
    }
```

My requirement is to add data into this map from componentDidMount() method by calling fetch() multiple times over a list of urls. Those map value will be used to populate columns of a datatable with image component.

I am confused over few points

- How to add data in the map one by one
- I may have to call nested fetch, will that cause any issue in updating the map due to presence of nested promise
- Whether this is possible to use this.state.imgSrcs.get('key') to populate the column even before the key is inserted

Please help me understand and let me know if more details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Below will be my thoughts on your questions.

1. How to add data in the map one by one.

** React detect reference change in state to refresh the component. Assuming you need to update state in button click, below is the click function.

```
function buttonClick() {
  const temp = new Map(imgSrcs);
  temp.set('newKey', 'newValue');
  this.state({imgSrcs: temp});
}
```

2. I may have to call nested fetch, will that cause any issue in updating the map due to presence of nested promise?

** Updating state in Nested fetch/API calls should not be an issue. But if you can, I would suggest to update state only once in innermost fetch call. So that will update component just once.

3. Whether this is possible to use this.state.imgSrcs.get('key') to populate the column even before the key is inserted?

** Not sure about the question, but `imgSrcs` is not populated then you cannot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So ```new Map(imgSrcs)``` will retain the existing values already added in the map. Regarding the third point I mean to say that the he map values need to be used somewhere and I have to add placeholder beforehand like, ```render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {this.state.imgSrcs.get('key')}
    </div>
    )
  }``` , so how that will work.